# Mixed-width operations for std::bitset

Tags: c++, api, bitset

When I was looking to use `std::bitset` instead of GCC's `__uint128` in my [RDS error-corrector](/q/214240), I found that it was hard to use, because there's no way to widen or truncate a bitset to one of another size.  Nor is there any ability to do bitwise arithmetic (`&`, `|`, `^`) or comparison (`==`, `!=`) with a bitset of different width.

I've identified the functions that I believe ought to be part of `std::bitset` and implemented them by wrapping the standard class.  To convert between different widths, I've had to go via `std::string`, but (as written in comment), an update to `std::bitset` would have a more direct (and exception-free) path.

I could have composed rather than inherited `std::bitset` - that's not really of concern here.  Please ignore the mechanics that deal with `my::bitset` being different to `std::bitset` and imagine that they are a single, larger class.  I'm most interested in whether the function signatures are correct and complete.

Note that (like the integers), widening can be implicit, but narrowing operations need to be explicit.  Most of the apparent duplication is to handle this distinction.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace my {

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct bitset : public std::bitset<N>
    {
        // forwarding of std::bitset constructors
        bitset()
            : std::bitset<N>{}
        {}

        template<typename T>
        requires std::is_unsigned_v<T>
        bitset(T n)
            : std::bitset<N>{n}
        {}

        template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
        explicit bitset(const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& str,
                        typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type pos = 0,
                        typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type n =
                        std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::npos)
            : std::bitset<N>{str, pos, n}
        {
        }

        // Widening and narrowing constructors, to be added to std::bitset

        // widening conversion
        template<std::size_t P>
        requires (P <= N)
        bitset(const std::bitset<P>& n) noexcept
            : std::bitset<N>{}
        {
            std::size_t i = n.size();
            while (i-- > 0) {
                this->set(i, n.test(i));
            }
        }

        // narrowing conversion
        template<std::size_t P>
        requires (P > N)
        explicit bitset(const std::bitset<P>& n) noexcept
            : std::bitset<N>{}
        {
            std::size_t i = this->size();
            while (i-- > 0) {
                this->set(i, n.test(i));
            }
        }
    };

    // Deduction guide for my::bitset
    template<std::size_t N>
    bitset(std::bitset<N>) -> bitset<N>;


    // Free functions to be added to namespace std

    // Deduction guide
    template<typename T>
    requires std::is_unsigned_v<T>
    bitset(T) -> bitset<sizeof (T) * CHAR_BIT>;


    // comparisons - widen as necessary
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator==(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N != Q)
    {
        if constexpr (N > Q)
            return a == bitset<N>{b};
        else
            return bitset<Q>{a} == b;
    }

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator!=(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
    {
        return ! (a == b);
    }

    // bitwise-and produces the narrower type
    // (a specific exception to "doing as the integers do")
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator&(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N > Q)
    {
        return bitset<Q>(a) & b;
    }

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator&(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N < Q)
    {
        return a & bitset<N>(b);
    }

    // bitwise-and assignment accepts a wider type
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator&=(bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N != Q)
    {
        return a &= bitset<N>(b);
    }

    // bitwise-or produces the wider type
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator|(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N < Q)
    {
        return bitset<Q>{a} | b;
    }

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator|(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N > Q)
    {
        return a | bitset<N>{b};
    }

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto& operator|=(bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N >= Q)
    {
        return a = a | bitset<N>{b};
    }

    // bitwise-xor produces the wider type
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator^(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N < Q)
    {
        return bitset<Q>{a} ^ b;
    }

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto operator^(const bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N > Q)
    {
        return a ^ bitset<N>{b};
    }

    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t Q>
    constexpr auto& operator^=(bitset<N>& a, const bitset<Q>& b)
        requires (N >= Q)
    {
        return a = a ^ bitset<N>{b};
    }

    template<std::size_t N, typename T>
    requires std::is_unsigned_v<T>
    constexpr auto operator^(const bitset<N>& a, const T& b)
    {
        return a ^ bitset<N>{b};
    }
    template<std::size_t N, typename T>
    requires std::is_unsigned_v<T>
    constexpr auto operator^(const T& a, const bitset<N>& b)
    {
        return bitset<N>{a} ^ b;
    }

}
```

---

I have a simple compilation test for the above code.  None of the mixed-width operations marked `// new` will compile with `std::bitset`; all the uncommented statements are fine with `my::bitset`.  The commented-out statements are intended to be errors (because they have a narrowing conversion without a cast).

```
#define NEW_BITSET

int main()
{
#ifdef NEW_BITSET
    using my::bitset;
#else
    using std::bitset;
#endif

    // Lower-case variables are narrow; upper-case are wide

    bitset<32> a{0xFFFF0000u};
    bitset<64> B{a ^ 0xFFFF00u};

    //bitset<32> b = B;         // error
    bitset<32> b{B};            // explicit conversion
    //auto b = bitset<32>{B};   // error

    bitset c = a & B;           // new;  c  is bitset<32>
    bitset D = a | B;           // new;  D  is bitset<64>
    bitset E = a ^ B;           // new;  E  is bitset<64>

    c &= b;                     // no change
    c &= B;                     // new (unlike |= and ^=)
    B &= c;                     // new

    c |= b;                     // no change
    //c |= B;                   // error
    D |= b;                     // new

    c ^= b;                     // no change
    //c ^= B;                   // error
    D ^= b;                     // new
    D &= E;                     // no change
}
```

I probably ought to use the Detection Idiom to assert that something shouldn't be valid, but I resorted to uncommenting the `// error` lines one at a time to prove them wrong.

---

I'm particularly looking for any errors or omissions in the **interface** of my mixed-width operations, but will happily take any criticism at all.

Answer (score 3):

One aspect that could surprise users is that operator `&` always *narrows* types to match.  That's a departure from the usual guidance of "do what the integers do".

On one hand, it makes sense not to waste resources on bits that will always be zero.  One of my own use cases is to extract the some or all of the lower 26 bits from a 130-bit value, so it seems reasonable to expect a 26-bit result.

On the other hand, it could catch users out when shifting the result.  These two functions will give different results:

```
auto fun_i(std::uint32_t a, std::uint16_t b) {
    return (a & b) << 16;
}

auto fun_b(my::bitset<32> a, my::bitset<16> b) {
    return (a & b) << 16;
}
```

On balance, I think that having to explicitly widen before shifting is a fair price to pay for saving resources when masking large numbers, but that would need to be well documented.  And I value dissenting opinions (in comments, please).